How to generate a project for every directory in Premake?
I have a large project with dozens of "modules" that are standalone (think plugins). Each module is sitting in its own folder. I want to generate a separate build target for each folder (loop rather than hardcoded), along with a single target that builds everything.
Since Premake is a Lua program is this possible? Can I just write some sort of loop in Lua with the body of the loop defining the project settings? I can't seem to find any examples or references to get started.
Simple project structure with root project and one sub-project per sub-folder.
MyProject
-Plugin1
-Plugin2
-Plugin3
-Plugin...


Once I started searching for Lua code examples I was able to piece together a solution. Here is my Premake script which creates one main project and then one for each sub-project. The main one builds everything.
workspace "MyApplication"
    basedir "./MyApplication"
    location "./MyApplication/IDE"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

project "MyApplication"
    basedir "./MyApplication"
    location "./MyApplication/IDE"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C"
    files { "./MyApplication/Includes/**Enum.h" }
    targetname "Plugins"
    targetdir "./MyApplication/Builds"
    objdir "./MyApplication/Builds/obj"
    includedirs { "./MyApplication/Includes" }

    filter { "system:android" }
        files { "./MyApplication/Plugins/**.all.c", "./MyApplication/Plugins/**.and.c" }
        files { "./MyApplication/Includes/**.all.h", "./MyApplication/Includes/**.and.h" }
        defines { "PLATFORM_AND" }

    filter { "system:ios" }
        files { "./MyApplication/Plugins/**.all.c", "./MyApplication/Plugins/**.ios.c" }
        files { "./MyApplication/Includes/**.all.h", "./MyApplication/Includes/**.ios.h" }
        defines { "PLATFORM_IOS" }

    filter { "system:linux" }
        files { "./MyApplication/Plugins/**.all.c", "./MyApplication/Plugins/**.lin.c" }
        files { "./MyApplication/Includes/**.all.h", "./MyApplication/Includes/**.lin.h" }
        defines { "PLATFORM_LIN" }

    filter { "system:macosx" }
        files { "./MyApplication/Plugins/**.all.c", "./MyApplication/Plugins/**.mac.c", "./MyApplication/Plugins/**.mac.m" }
        files { "./MyApplication/Includes/**.all.h", "./MyApplication/Includes/**.mac.h" }
        defines { "PLATFORM_MAC" }

    filter { "system:windows" }
        files { "./MyApplication/Plugins/**.all.c", "./MyApplication/Plugins/**.win.c" }
        files { "./MyApplication/Includes/**.all.h", "./MyApplication/Includes/**.win.h" }
        defines { "PLATFORM_WIN" }

    filter { "configurations:Debug" }
        defines { "DEBUG" }
        symbols "On"
        targetdir "./MyApplication/Builds/Debug/bin"
        objdir "./MyApplication/Builds/Debug/bin"

    filter { "configurations:Release" }
        defines { "NDEBUG" }
        optimize "On"
        targetdir "./MyApplication/Builds/Release/bin"
        objdir "./MyApplication/Builds/Release/bin"

-- Generate sub-projects
printf("Generating sub-projects")
directories = os.matchdirs("./MyApplication/Plugins/*")
-- alphabetize everything so it appears in correct order
table.sort(directories)
for dirCount = 1, #directories do
    local dir = directories[dirCount]
    local dirName = path.getname(dir)
    print ("Generating project for " .. dirName)
    project (dirName)
        kind "StaticLib"
        language "C"
        files { "./MyApplication/Includes/**Enum.h" }
        files { dir .. "/**.all.c",  "./MyApplication/Includes/**.all.h"}
        targetname (dirName)
        targetdir (dir .. "/Builds")
        objdir  (dir .. "/Builds")
        includedirs { "./MyApplication/Includes" }

        filter { "system:macosx" }
            files { dir .. "/**.mac.c", dir .. "/**.mac.m" }
            files { "./MyApplication/Includes/**.mac.h" }
            defines { "PLATFORM_MAC" }

        filter { "system:windows" }
            files { dir .. "/**.win.c" }
            files { "./MyApplication/Includes/**.win.h" }
            defines { "PLATFORM_WIN" }

        filter { "configurations:Debug" }
            defines { "DEBUG" }
            symbols "On"
            targetdir (dir .. "/Builds")
            objdir (dir .. "/Builds")
end


I suggest to move generic stuff outside of filter, i.e  files { dir .. "/**.all.c", dir .. "/**.all.h"}

Whereas premake prepend configuration for objdir, it doesn't for targetdir (which is identical for Release/Debug in your case :/)
